# Google Sheet restructure, Columns/Rows from Sheet A - to Row based in Sheet B

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am pretty good with google sheets, using advanced functions. However, this issue has perplexed me for a long time. The current format of a sheet, "Current Sheet" below is a sheet that end-users use to enter figures.

I need, using formulas (not copy-and-paste) to structure that data in another sheet like you see below in the "What I Need" sheet. This data is ultimately going to be read via python script with rows inserted into a database.

The dates are Jan-Dec, and there are over 30 Categories. Every category has a Month value.

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The following formula returns the data structured as desired:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Month","Item","Value";SPLIT(FLATTEN(B1:C1&"♣"&A4:A14&"♣"&B4:C14), "♣")})
```

- The [`=ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) allows you to do operations with the ranges, therefore I've added on the outer level
- First, a concatenation of "Months" range + "Categories" range + values range, separated by any arbitrary delimiter in order to `=SPLIT` later on.
- Then, [`=FLATTEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) this result to get a single column
- Then the `=FLATTEN` result is [`=SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) by the delimiter and put into a [defined array](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) as second row.
- The first row is manually set with header labels.

Comment: Was not aware of the FLATTEN function. That you, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=index({"Month","Item","Value";split(flatten(transpose(eomonth(B1:C1,-1)+1&"❄️"&A4:A14&"❄️"&B4:C14)),"❄️")})
```

[image]